# How can I put text before a random number in a <p>?

Tags: javascript, html, string, concatenation

I'm trying to insert a `Math.random()` into text so it would say "your number is" and then the number from the `Math.random()`. I can see that it I  possible from this line of code: `alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);`. It shows you what you've copied but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that with `Math.random()`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo")
  x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 89999) + 10000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to display a random 5 digit number.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <p>I want it to say something before the number like 'order #' and then the random number</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What like this? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GF1Q3ZX5JS6I

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 89999) + 10000);
```

Use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), like so:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo")
  x.innerHTML = `You generated ${Math.floor((Math.random() * 89999) + 10000)}`;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to display a random 5 digit number.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Template strings allow you to easily combine strings and JS code. You can put text in the template string as you would a normal string. You can also put JavaScript code that will be evaluated, converted to a string, and placed in the template string by enclosing it in `${...}`. Template strings are ver powerful and can be used to do much more than the simple example I showed above. I suggest you read the documentation about them I linked above.

Alternatively, you could just concatenate strings by using the + operator. Here's an example

```
x.innerHTML = "You generated " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 89999) + 10000).toString();
```

Both have the same effect, but template strings are more powerful and are a best practice whenever possible.

Comment: oh wow thanks so much! i didnt even think about template string but that works perfectly.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, you should accept it by clicking the check mark. This indicates that the answer is correct and answered your question. By accepting the answer, you help others who find the question better understand how to solve their issue, too.